# Dealing with adding 'positive' and negative' values in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a custom attribute attached to elements in my DOM. This attr is being passed a value from my DB. I want to add these values together.

```
var value = jQuery('option:selected', id).attr('cust_attr');
```

If all of these values are positive numbers, everything is fine. But any negative numbers are being treated as zero. I'm using math.max to add these numbers together,

```
total += Math.max(0,value);
```

Obviously I would like the negative numbers to subtract from the total.
Would anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't get, why you use `Math.max()`?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment... Have a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Math.max(0,value)` gets the maximum between 0 and value. If value is negative, it will return 0.
Just using `total += value;` should be enough.